# Can I add a custom Id to Session::create so I can retrieve it in a webhook?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Basically, following the stripe [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart?lang=php#create), you create a checkout session

```
  $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'line_items' => [[
      'price' => $prices->data[0]->id,
      'quantity' => 1,
    ]],
    'mode' => 'subscription',
    'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
  ]);
```

The user gets redirected to stripe, completes the transaction, gets redirected back to the website, and the `events` for the `webhook` fire.

Now in the webhook listener, you can get the info about the payment and customer, but I have no idea who that customer is on my end.

So, can I attach some custom data to the `Session::create` so I can identify witch user made the purchase in the webhook listener on the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `metadata` **object**  in your session create call to Stripe with all custom data that you'd like to add for eg, `customerId` of your database. When the webhook is triggered, stripe will post the `metadata` object along with other fields listed here.

So your code should look like

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
'line_items' => [[
  'price' => $prices->data[0]->id,
  'quantity' => 1,
]],
'mode' => 'subscription',
'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
'metadata' => [
      'customerId' => 'some-value'
]
]);
```

[Read more](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata)